# Uninstall Adobe Creative Cloud without removing pre-existing app

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-creative-cloud

I had a pre-existing installation of Adobe Photoshop CS6 when I installed a free trial of Premiere Pro, which required me to install Adobe Creative Cloud. This version of Photoshop is standalone and has always worked completely independently of Creative Cloud.

Now, Creative Cloud has somehow associated itself with Photoshop, and I am prevented from uninstalling Creative Cloud because:

> You still have Creative Cloud applications installed on your computer that require it.

This error appears when trying to uninstall through "Programs and Features" on Windows 10.

How do I remove Creative Cloud without uninstalling Photoshop?

Comment: What OS? On Mac, all CC uninstallers are in Apps/Utilities. idk whether windows has specific uninstallers, but it sounds like you're trying to get a generic uninstaller to work, rather than a specific one.

Comment: Windows. This error was obtained when trying to uninstall Creative Cloud through "Programs and Features". I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: It might not be possible to remove the _Adobe Creative Cloud_ Static Software Application without uninstalling everything else that is produced by the _Adobe_ Corporation. This might be the Intended Design. If you really want to get rid of it, uninstall everything else and then reinstall what you still need. Think of the bright side: there are Static Software Applications, such as _McAfee_'s Anti-Malware Desktop Suites, that are *never* uninstallable, except through a Clean Reinstallation Procedure of the Operating System.We remember dearly a Forum Thread intensively discussing that situation.

Comment: Urgh. How obnoxious. I was hoping I might at least be able to go into Safe Mode and delete it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by uninstalling Photoshop, uninstalling Creative Cloud, and then reinstalling Photoshop, much to my frustration.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool from adobe

1. Go to the [Adobe webpage](http://www.adobe.com)
2. Search for `AdobeCreativeCloudCleanerTool.exe`
3. Download it.
4. Run the tool.

You may find interesting [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html).

Comment: I couldn't get this to work but perhaps I just chose the wrong option. I ended up having to uninstall Photoshop, uninstall Creative Cloud, then reinstall Photoshop.

Comment: @Dan you can write the above as an answer... `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

> There is a tool from adobe

> Go to the Adobe webpage
> Search for AdobeCreativeCloudCleanerTool.exe
> Download it.
> Run the tool.
> You may find interesting this page.

This works, windows cant uninstall CC only without uninstalling photoshop but following these steps takes you to an uninstaller that actually works.